Enabling browser camera access from Dockerfile
Can somebody help figure out how to enable camera access in the web python app that is run in docker. Obviously, it runs well when I run it locally. This is the code I try to run:
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
import cv2
import signal
import sys
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

# Initialize the camera
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def generate_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # Capture frame-by-frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')  # Serve the HTML template


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


def cleanup(*args):
    """Release the camera resource when the app stops."""
    print("Releasing camera...")
    camera.release()
    sys.exit(0)


# Handle signals for a clean exit
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cleanup)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cleanup)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, host="0.0.0.0")  # Allow connections from all IPs

And this is a Dockerfile I create to build:
# Use a lightweight Python image
FROM python:3.10

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /flaskProject

# Install required system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-0 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 5005

# Run the Flask application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

Maybe somebody tried to use the camera in web app with docker before? Thank you! Would really appreciate your help.
